# R Optimisation of the calculation of the geographical distance between a large number of polygons (>11.000)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gis, r-sf, geosphere

How can I optimise in R the calculation of the geographical distance between millions of pairs of centroids of polygons?

The polygons represent 111 km x 111 km grid cells covering the entire Earth.
I'm using the `st_distance` R function. But the high number of polygons (>11,000) suppose a computational challenge. Any suggestions on how to optimize it? In terms of accuracy, it does not need to be overly precise.

Toy code:

```
# Create a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with five polygons
polygons <- st_as_sfc(list(
  st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0), c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0)))),
  st_polygon(list(cbind(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1), c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0)))),
  st_polygon(list(cbind(c(2, 2, 3, 3, 2), c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0)))),
  st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0, 0, -1, -1, 0), c(0, -1, -1, 0, 0)))),
  st_polygon(list(cbind(c(-1, -1, -2, -2, -1), c(0, -1, -1, 0, 0))))
))
st_crs(polygons)=4326
data <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
polygons <- st_sf(polygons, data)

# Get the centroids of the polygons and calculate the distance
centroids <- st_centroid(polygons$polygons)
distance <- st_distance(centroids)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are several packages available in R that allow you to compute a distance matrix using various distance functions (e.g. Haversine, Vincenty, geodesic). Here is a comparison of 4 packages and `{geodist}` seems to be the fastest. Note that the distance results are different.

```r
library("sf")
library("terra")
library("geodist")
library("geosphere")

n = 4000
df = data.frame(x = runif(n, -180, 180), y = runif(n, -90, 90))
pts_sf = st_as_sf(df, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = "epsg:4326")
pts_terra = vect(df, geom = c("x", "y"), crs = "epsg:4326")

t = bench::mark(
  iterations = 5, check = FALSE,
  sf = st_distance(pts_sf),
  terra = as.matrix(terra::distance(pts_terra)),
  geodist = geodist(df, measure = "haversine"),
  geosphere = distm(df, fun = distHaversine)
)
t[, 1:5]
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
#> 1 sf           20.57s   20.76s    0.0480  125.77MB
#> 2 terra        13.02s   13.11s    0.0764  579.85MB
#> 3 geodist    791.53ms 806.79ms    1.24    244.34MB
#> 4 geosphere     2.68s    2.83s    0.351     2.81GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on scale and required accuracy, you could `st_transform` your coordinates to an equidistant / equal-area [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections).

Then, round your centroid coordinates and convert to integer (this will return your coordinates in meters, for finer resolution convert to dm or similar before; the expected performance increase comes from using integers together with `dist`).

Finally use `dist` to obtain a distance matrix. Using your example data `polygons`:

```
df <- 
  polygons |>
  st_transform(3035) |> ## Lambert equal area, picked randomly
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(coords = polygons |> 
           st_centroid() |> 
           st_coordinates(),
         x = coords[1], y = coords[2]
  ) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  select(Name, x, y) |>
  mutate(across(x:y, ~ round(.x, 0) |> as.integer()))
```

set unique rownames to identify centroids in the distance matrix later on:

```
rownames(df) <- df$Name
```

```
> df
  Name       x        y
A    A 3150682 -2248929
B    B 3273461 -2261293
C    C 3396377 -2272283
D    D 3022547 -2334767
E    E 2899563 -2319670
```

calculate distance:

```
df |> select(x:y) |> dist()
```

```
         A        B        C        D
B 123400.0                           
C 246802.4 123406.3                  
D 154229.5 261450.3 379016.0         
E 260892.8 378427.8 499068.8 123907.2
```

Comment: It does not need to be overly precise and the polygons represent 111 km x 111 km grid cells covering the entire Earth. But I am not sure if your kind proposal is adequate.
**Real example**: Two remote grid cells with _centroids_ (-162.4717, 69.26965 and  121.533 -19.7937) and with _coordinates x and y_ (-162, 69 and 122, -20). The result with `st_distance` = 11526154, while with `dist` = 297.6189. `st_distance` give the results in [m], as well as what you suggest for `dist`. The results are highly different. I may be doing something wrong, but is it possible that the differences are so high?

Comment: You need to project geographic coordinates (degrees) to a planar coordinate system (preferably equidistant) *before* calculating distance. `st_distance` knows it's dealing with geodetic lines (distances on a spheric surface) from the CRS, but `dist` assumes points on a plane.

Comment: I'm afraid this can only work for points that are up to 180 degrees apart on the sphere.