# Aggregating points in dataframe based on distance

Tags: r, dplyr, mapping, geospatial, r-sf

I have a set of Lat/Long points with numerical values attached to each point. Essentially I want to perform basic calculations on the numerical values within 300,000m of each point, but initially just trying to sum the values as I should be able to work out how to make the calculations more complex from there. Additionally the dataset is large (~200,000 rows) which seems to be the current bottleneck.

I currently have the following:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(units)

test <-data.frame(Longitude=rnorm(2e5),Latitude=rnorm(2e5),ncol=runif(2e5, min=0, max=100))
pt = st_as_sf(x = test,coords = c("Longitude","Latitude"),crs = 4326)
st_distance(pt,pt[1,])<set_units(300000,m)
```

My logic being for each row find the other rows which are within the radius, then use this information to filter (and sum) on these rows. However given the datasize I seem to be hitting a brickwall, also I am not certain this is the most efficient way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are ways to do this, but can you make it clearer what you're asking? A naive distance matrix of m points would be m^2 values, which would be too large here. Your points need an ID if you're going to create a boolean matrix of >n metres. You don't seem to have one - you have a column called `ncol` which is a random float - is that meant to define the number of columns? Is it an ID? What do you want the output to look like? Can you give an example with something like 5 points?

Comment: @SamR ncol is just a random numerical value assigned to each point. So for example I would want to sum the ncol values for all of the points in test dataframe which are within 300,000m of the first point, and then the second pt etc. So the ideal outputs would be just the test dataframe with an additional column showing the aggregated ncol values of all points within 300,000m of that row. I'm currently locked out of editing the question but will update with an example when I am able to.

Comment: You're not going to want to calculate the distances 200k times. Best thing to do is calculate as many as you can at once and either save them to disk. I'd use `data.table` and `spatialrisk::haversine()` for this - they'll save some time.

Comment: Check also this simple benchmark for calculating distances between points in geographic reference system: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75485630

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using st_buffer(), that creates a circle with the given radius and then use st_intersect() to filter the points that are into it. I mean, try:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(units)

test <-data.frame(Longitude=rnorm(2e5),Latitude=rnorm(2e5),ncol=runif(2e5, min=0, max=100))
pt = st_as_sf(x = test,coords = c("Longitude","Latitude"),crs = 4326)

st_intersects(I(st_buffer(pt[1,], set_units(300000,m)))$geometry,pt %>% rowwise) 
# Here, it took around 10s to run
```

Comment: Actually, around 8.4s. I'd suggest that you use a `for`  structure and look only to the new points, using what you have already done (like, if point 1 and point 10 are within 300km, you know 10 and 1 are within 10km and don't need to calculate it again)